# Is the term "krapfens" popular/well-known in English?

Tags: dialects, loanwords, food

The word *krapfens* means "donuts": in Italy it is quite common to see it in German as well as in English; I guess that's because Italian borrows many original expressions from foreign languages.

It seems to me that in in England, in America and in other countries where English is the official language, the situation is different: people don't borrow many original words and expressions from other languages and consequently they like words which are easy-to-spell, therefore non-English words may be less popular.

Given that, I guess *donuts* is more popular than *krapfens* to point out the same object. Am I wrong?

- Which is the most used between "krapfens" and "donuts", in English?
- Or, alternatively, if I say *krapfens* to a native English speaker, does he/she immediately grasp what I meant to point out (as if I said "donuts") ?

[image]

Comment: Krapfen is not used in BrE and AmE to refer to a donut.

Comment: This is a question and answer site for linguists, etymologists, and serious English language enthusiasts. Please get help in drafting your posts without spelling, punctuation and grammatical errors.

Comment: @Kris thank you for your suggestion , I edited my question.

Comment: ***Krapfen, Italian by adoption for two hundered years*** http://www.italianways.com/krapfen-italian-by-adoption-for-two-hundred-years/

Comment: In British English the spelling is **doughnut** nothing easy about that word.

Comment: It's not true that English does not borrow from other languages, think of inimitable French expressions such as "déjà vu" and "c'est la vie" (not easy spellings either),  and words that were derived from Latin such as *impossible*, *instruction*,  and *intelligent*. Never heard of *Karaoke*? Or the word *pyjamas*? The [**list is endless**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lists_of_English_words_by_country_or_language_of_origin)!

Comment: *Ich bin ein krapfen!*

Comment: @Mari-LouA - there is a term for krapfen in English which has not been mentioned here...but I can't remember it...

Comment: @Josh61 A *jelly roll*? A *bear claw*? Sometimes mini, spherical doughnuts are called *doughnut/donut **holes*** (because they're s'posed to be the "missing part" of the standard doughnut), or *munchkins* by one famous vendor (named after the race of little people in the famous work *The Wizard of Oz*). Or, returning to German, the famous *Berliner*?

Comment: @DanBron - no, a term I had never heard before, starting with s...but I really can't remeber..

Comment: @Josh61 Perhaps [*struffoli*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Struffoli): *a Neapolitan dish made of deep fried balls of dough about the size of marbles.*

Comment: @Josh61 This is gonna bug me! I went through Wikipedia's list of pastries, and there wasn't anything listed under "s" that hit the mark. So maybe something like *cruller*? Or the Mexican-cum-American treat the *churro* (an unfurled doughnut). At star fairs and such, we have plain old *fried dough*, or *fritters*, and in New York pizza shops when I was growing up, back when they were still principally owned and run by Italians (well, Italian-Americans), they sold *zeppole*. But even then it was a fair niche term, understood by Italians and New Yorkers, and today I doubt even New Yorkers know t.

Comment: Another word for fairground fried dough is *funnel cake*. And, now that I think of it, in New Orleans, and presumably other French creole places, they have *beignets*. Edit: ok, I just found a Wikipedia list [*specific to different kinds & names of fried dough*](http://bit.ly/1I1Xs8p) (I love living in the future!). It turns out there is a treat called a *sopaipilla*, which is mostly associated with Latin American nations, but apparently hs also found its way into th cuisine of (specifically) [New Mexico and Colorado](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sopaipilla#cite_note-note_1-9). Was that it?

Comment: @DanBron - thanks for your detailed research, the term came up recently is a similar question here about cookies. I may be wrong but I feel sure I saw it referring to a krapfen or something similar. I'll keep you posted!:)

Comment: @DanBron Has anyone ever confirmed that rumor (I believe it was first mentioned by Len Deighton) about the usage of "Berliner"? I have heard some German people tell me that although a Berliner was a pastry, JFK was understood in his intent.

Comment: @Gandalf Wikipedia says that the idea that JFK misspoke or Germans understood him to be talking about doughnuts is [a misconception](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ich_bin_ein_Berliner#Jelly_doughnut_misconception), and dispenses with the argument pretty thoroughly.

Answer (score 4):

On the contrary, English has an extremely rich vocabulary *because* is has adopted so many foreign words.

It is natural that the German term is commonly known in Italy, since northern Italy has a sizeable native population of German-speakers (62.3 percent of the population of Trentino Alto Adige / South Tyrol). England obviously does not, but the large number of German-speaking migrants to North America have gifted the English language with many, many loan words, particularly for food.

As to the question of why *krapfen* is not a commonly known term in English, when a perfectly serviceable word already exists in English, it can be hard for alternative word to gain traction. *Doughnuts* has been in the English language since roughly 1800 ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doughnut#History)), and it is more descriptive to the English ear than *krapfen* and lacks the scatological connotation, so it is not surprising that *doughnut* is common and *krapfen* obscure.

Comment: I am not sure what "scatological connotation" *doughnuts,* *donuts* or *krapfen* have or have to do with in any way.

Comment: Actually the are ***very few German words***  that are used in Italy,  krapfen  is probably the more common, while there are tens  of English terms that are  more and more commonly used.

Comment: @Kris Krapfen -> Crap fen. Crap = excrement. Fen = bog, swamp. Is it just me that thinks this word does not sound delicious?

Comment: Any -cious or not, it is irrelevant to context, and is it just me that thinks the mention is perverse? Look here: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Krapfen#German and here: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/krapfen

Comment: @mikeagg your observation is very interesting. If the word gives such impression to the english speakers, it might be counterproductive using it to define sweets...

Comment: @Josh61 I think you get German loan words in Italian more frequently for food. "Speck" (a kind of ham) comes to mind.

Comment: @robertalrp Worth pointing out that many native speakers, of the British English variety, happily and readily consume a dish named *spotted dick*. For whatever that's worth to you.

Comment: @DanBron - I agree, I don't think that the sound of the term has much to do with its adoption as a regular word for food...there is a variety of cookies called "le ossa dei morti" (the bones of the dead) which are delicious, everybody loves them.

Comment: @Josh61 Next time I'm in Italy I'm going to go all sorts of places and ask "do you sell the bones of the dead here?".

Comment: @DanBron - you'll love it. https://www.google.it/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=ossa%20dei%20morti%20dolci

Comment: @Josh61 How about ‘Le Palle Di Nonno Fritte' -which translates on the menu as "Fried Grandfather's Balls"

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you need to consider first why loan words enter a language. Three reasons suggest themselves to me:

1. The need to communicate with people speaking another language, especially because of trade or military occupation.
2. The need to refer to a new object. The prime examples here are technological and culinary.
3. A desire to appear fashionable (in the general sense) by preferring words from a culture thought to be fashionable to perfectly adequate words in one's own language.

Let us look briefly at **British English** in relation to these categories.

1. The last occupation of Britain was by the Norman French. What may initially have been loan words to Anglo-Saxon (or whatever) eventually became one part of a fusion to English. British English acquired some loan words through the reverse process: Indian words such as 'bungalow' from the British Raj. 
   For the rest, trade would seem to have been dominant, although this spills into category 2. Fabrics such as 'organdie' come to mind. There are some German loan words from the Second World War, 'blitz' and 'ersatz' (?), although, again, these might be considered new concepts.
2. New food vocabulary requires the food to be introduced and popular. Doughnuts were not widespread in Britain until after the 1960s, and came from the USA. Britain has its own sausage culture and German sausages are a delicatessen (loan word of this general category) item. Presumably they came to Italy (würstel) from the North. They also came to the US (from German immigrants?) as 'wieners'. More important in Britain was the influence of French cuisine, and this brought loan words such as 'eclair' and 'gateau'. And Italian cuisine brought older acquisitions such as 'spaghetti' and more recent ones such as 'pizza'. 
   New technological objects in recent years have tended to be predominately of US or British origin so, it is the English word such as 'computer' that may be borrowed by other European language (eg German: 'Komputer', although French 'logiciel'). You might say that the word 'program' (only used for computer instructions in British English) is a loan word from the US because of its spelling, but I imagine that is debatable. Older technology gave rise to loan words in English like 'Daguerreotype' (French photographic process).
3. In the 19th and early 20th century the British regarded French as the fashionable culture in the arts and in fashion. So there are numerous French loan words or phrases in British English (some, such as 'cul de sac' are actually quite meaningless to a Frenchman). However, there are an order of magnitude fewer German loan words because there was no such feeling about Germany. 
   Given the Anglo-Saxon association of France with high fashion, it is ironic that perusal of a contemporary French fashion magazine reveals expressions such as 'le looking' and 'les peoples', although these are rather a case of "the revenge of the cul-de-sac". So now the US is fashionable, thanks to cinema, TV, and popular culture. US English loan words have therefore crept into British English: a good example is the gradual replacement of the British 'lorry' by the US 'truck'.

In conclusion, the introduction of loan words into British English, as with other languages, has specific causes, and is not the result of the whims of individuals, as the question implies.